# Modifying parent internal snapshot in QCOW2

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

Spent some time trying to cope with next problem I faced.

I'm using internal QCOW2 snapshots for my VM and it has next tree:

```
parent
  |
  +- child1
  |
  +- child2
```

which was gotten by taking *parent* snapshot making some changes in it and taking *child1* snapshot than reverting to *parent* again making some other changes and taking *child2* snapshot.

After some time I had to update some files which originally came from parent snapshot.
So the question is **if I can somehow rebase my child snapshots on *parent*?**

Btw, had some experiments with converting from internal snapshots to external (through backing files) and than to committing em and taking internal snapshots once more but had no luck.